# Why is my query string value being lost after the page is loaded for a certain amount of time?

Tags: c#, query-string, session-variables, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

Quick scenario for you.

I have in my page tried to restore a value to a session variable in the event that it is cleared, using a query string, like so:

```
if(Session["species"] == null || Session["species"] == "")
{
    Session["species"] = Request["species"];
}
```

Further down, I set the value of one of two other session variables, based off of the value of this session variable, like so:

```
if((string)Session["species"]=="Canine")
{
    Session["dBreed"] = Request.Form["breed"].Trim();
}
else if((string)Session["species"]=="Feline")
{
    Session["cBreed"] = Request.Form["breed"].Trim();
}
```

However, it seems that once the session times out (after 20 mins, I believe), I still get this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 134:            errorMessage = "The data received from the \"Age\" field was invalid.";
Line 135:        }
Line 136:        if(((string)Session["dBreed"]).Length > 50)
Line 137:        {
Line 138:            errorMessage = "The data received from the \"Breed\" field was invalid.";

Source File: c:\Users\cradebaugh\Documents\My Web Sites\Vaccinations\InputEntry.cshtml    

(ERRORS ON):  Line: 136
```

Clearly, I understand what has happened (that the value of Session["dBreed"] was never assigned, which can mean only that Session["species"] variable never got reassigned after being cleared.

My question is: Is trying to request the query string (using Request["species"]) only good on a page after a certain amount of time or is something else occurring altogether?

I can physically see the query string in my URL, and all, but it seems that the value I am requesting is no longer there by the time the session times out.

I already plan to simply use a hidden input field to try and achieve the same goal as above, however, I thought it best to understand the nature of the use of query strings in this manner, before I use them again in the future.

Thank you for your time, and any help you may offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... the value of Session["dBreed"] was never assigned, which can mean only that Session["species"] variable never got reassigned ...

Or that the `Session["species"]` was set to `"Feline"`. Looking at your second code-block:

```
else if((string)Session["species"]=="Feline")
{
    Session["cBreed"] = Request.Form["breed"].Trim();
}
```

if the species is `"Feline"`, you assign `Session["cBreed"]`, not `Session["dBreed"]`.

Comment: It seems that this is what is going on. I forgot, that, even though I only intend on ever calling or using the Session variable if it is plotted, totally forgetting that including it in my code, at all, means it will produce said compiler error. Do I have that about right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was it. Honestly, I should have seen this, but, ugh, it's so easy to miss things, sometimes. I am thrilled to know that (as I originally thought) query strings are available for (Request) not for a limited time only :)

Comment: @VoidKing: It's not producing a compiler error; it's just throwing an exception when you try to access the `Length` property of a `string` which is `null`. When it executes `((string)Session["dBreed"]).Length` and the `Session["dBreed"]` returns `null`, the `Length` property will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that everything that wasn't a logic error or a run-time error was a compiler error, but this is considered a runtime error, isn't it? Anyway, thanks, so much!